# Enable tabbed product display in BigCommerce

Tags: tabs, bigcommerce

By default, product information is displayed in an accordion format, e.g., "details, specs, warranty," etc. BigCommerce offers an option to display in tabbed format, but it doesn't work in any of the templates I have tried. In user settings, there is a check box to "enable tabbed format." Checking it does nothing. It's bug fix time and I can't quite get it. Here are the two files in question (I think):

```
    %%GLOBAL_ProductTabsControlScript%%
<div class="Panel" id="ProductTabs">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        lang.Description = '%%LNG_JS_Description%%';
        lang.Warranty = '%%LNG_JS_Warranty%%';
        lang.OtherDetails = '%%LNG_JS_OtherDetails%%';
        lang.ProductTags = '%%LNG_JS_Tags%%';
        lang.SimilarProducts = '%%LNG_JS_SimilarProducts%%';
        lang.Reviews = '%%LNG_JS_Reviews%%';
        lang.OtherProducts = '%%LNG_JS_OtherProducts%%';
        lang.ProductVideos = '%%LNG_JS_ProductVideos%%';
        lang.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews = '%%LNG_JS_SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%';       
    </script>
    %%GLOBAL_ProductTabsOptimizerScriptTag%%
    <!-- Remove the code from here to create the no product tabs version of the product page
        <ul class="TabNav" id="ProductTabsList">
        </ul>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            var HideProductTabs = 0;
        //]]></script>
    %%GLOBAL_ProductTabsOptimizerNoScriptTag%% -->
</div>
```

And then here is the call in the actual single products (Panels/ProductDetails.html) file

```
%%Panel.ProductTabs%%

            <div id="prodAccordion">
                %%Panel.ProductDescription%%
                %%Panel.ProductVideos%%
                %%Panel.ProductWarranty%%
                %%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%
                %%Panel.SimilarProductsByTag%%
                %%Panel.ProductByCategory%%
                %%Panel.ProductVendorsOtherProducts%%
                %%Panel.ProductReviews%%
            </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a bug. The feature is only supported in a select number of themes that have since been deprecated (referred to as legacy themes).